# Conservation Laws and time-reversal symmetry

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, discrete, time-reversal-symmetry

In most dynamics books I've read they refer to conservation laws and their associated symmetries, cf. [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). I know that

- the conservation of momentum is a result of the homogenity of space
- angular momentum is the result of isotropic space
- and the conservation of energy is the result of the homogenity of time.

Is there a fourth conservation law that would result from time-reversal symmetry?