# Which is the integrals of the motion deriving from the isotropy of time?

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, time-reversal-symmetry, integrals-of-motion

In Landau's Mechanics it is written that there are some integrals of the motion deriving from  the fundamental homogeneity and isotropy of space and time. Momentum is related to the homogeneity of space; energy to the homogeneity of time; angular momentum to the isotropy of space. Which is the integral deriving from the isotropy of time?

Comment: What do you mean by "istropy of time"?  How do you rotate time?

Comment: It means that replacing $t$ with $-t$ the Lagrangian is unchanged and thus the laws of classical mechanics are reversible.

Comment: $t\to -t$ is not a continuous transformation. Constants of the motion arise  from continuous transformations, not discrete ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185264/2451