# What is the conservation law associated with isotropy of time?

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, discrete, time-reversal-symmetry

I am reading Landau and Lifshitz’s Mechanics, where they explain how the conservation of momentum and angular momentum follow from the homogeneity and isotropy of space, respectively. They also show how the conservation of energy follows from the homogeneity of time. This makes me wonder if there is a similar conservation law that follows from the isotropy of time?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your distinction between homogeneity and isotropy of time?

Comment: There is a single direction of time so it is necessarily isotropic.

Comment: In my mind, the isotropy of time means physics law is the same in every time direction (analogous to space isotropy). Based on that logic, time has two directions, forward and backwards.

Comment: Then you are talking about time reversal. This is not a symmetry of the standard model. And even if you neglect this, it's a discrete symmetry. I.e. one that has no associated conservation law.

Comment: entropy is conserved in a reversible process

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693073/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Since time is only one dimensional, the only possible "isotropy" would be symmetry under time reversal. But that is a discrete symmetry and Noether's theorem only works for continuous symmetries. So there is no conservation law associated with isotropy of time.